# ImagMagick: How to add a gradient splice to an image using one convert command?

Tags: imagemagick, gradient, splice, imagemagick-convert

Is it possible to add a gradient splice to the bottom of an image? It seems that gradient option [requires](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#gradient) -size, which I cannot provide because size of the image may varry.

It's possible with convert and compose but I want to use only one command. Something like this (note that this is invalid currently):

```
convert -fill gradient:black-white -gravity south splice 0x20 image1.jpg image2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. My suggestion to you is to use `-append` instead of `-splice`.
2. The image size may vary, but you can recognize the width by running `identify -format %W image1.jpg`.

So one possible command to achieve what you want is:

```
convert                                                \
    input.jpg                                          \
   -size $(identify -format %W input.jpg)x20 gradient: \
   -append                                             \
    output.jpg
```

---

**Update:**

Above command works on Linux, Unix or Mac OS X, but not on Windows. On Windows, the most simple way to achieve the same you'd use something like these two commands:

```
for /f "usebackq delims= " %I in (`identify -format %W input.jpg`) do set width=%I
convert  input.jpg  -size %width%x20  gradient:  -append  output.jpg
```

The above is for direct execution in a cmd.exe window. If you put the commands into a batch file, you need to modify the `%I` to make it `%%I`:

(Sorry, I don't have a Windows system around right now in order to verify the precise syntax...)

**Update2:**
[Windows bat alternative for Bash inline command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929493/windows-bat-alternative-for-bash-inline-command)

Comment: Is there any alternative for  $(identify -format %W input.jpg)x20 in Windows?

Comment: @Mohsen: So as per \@paxdiablo's confirmation, my version would also have worked (though it was more explicit than required)...